# How do I complete the alien crystal mystery?

Tags: surviving-mars

I've discovered several alien crystals that start producing rare metals when powered up.

How do I complete they mystery? How many crystals are there to find, and do I need to power them up all at the same time or can I power them one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to complete the mystery all crystals must be powered simultaneously. Note that not all crystals appear near your starting location, they are scattered across the map so most likely you will have to scan each sector before you're able to complete the mystery.